# Jtable not working and Jframe not closing (JAVA)

Tags: java

```
public class answer{

    String[] clomn;
    Integer[][] disparray;

    public answer(int[][] x) {

        clomn = new String[x.length];
        disparray = new Integer[x.length][x[0].length];

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
             for(int k = 0;k < x[0].length; k++){

                 int temp = x[i][k];
                 disparray[i][k] =  Integer.valueOf(temp);
             }

          clomn[i] = " ";    
        }
    }

    public void ans_printer(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Result");
        JTable asd = new JTable(disparray, clomn);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(450,450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.add(asd);
    }   
}
```

I don't have any error in console. But the window is not closing. I got to open task manager and close it. And the JTable is Black, for this I think the conversion between int to integer is not correct. And why Black color is appearing? My background is red. And black is not evenly distributed in the window as there's a small rectangle of white color. And if I resize the window it does not it stays as it is.
So my questions:

1. Is that conversion correct?
2. Why is that black color?
3. Why it is not closing?

I can open task manger. Resize the window with smooth animations (of the operating system of course). Lastly I wanna provide the code that calls the method.

```
answer abc = new answer(newM);
abc.ans_printer();
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT7K2.png)

Comment: please start class names with a capital letter. it's convention.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxtaAvBbWoVjcVNJdUMzM0pSdUE/view ScreenShot of window.

Comment: please don't use the comments for this type of information. upload the image to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but this is what fixed my problem.

```
disparray[i][k] =  new Integer(x [i][k]);
```

Can anyone explain me what is happening above .